# How do I make Serilog overwrite previous log file on rollover?

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

The title basically. I want Serilog to overwrite the log file on rollover and not create log-001, log-002 etc. There doesn't seem to be any option to do that from what I see in the references.

Of course it's possible to query the file size and delete it if it grows too big. But is there any way to handle this from within Serilog?

Comment: did you try to set `retainedFileCountLimit` to 0 or 1 ?

Comment: 0 is an invalid parameter. 1 keeps the latest log, which would be log-010 for example.

Comment: yes, so you'll have max 2 files - current and rolled. Why do you need to override current? do you want to save some space? What is the motivation?

Comment: There's no "business" need for this. I am just curious. Seems like something a logger should give an option for.

Comment: this is rather odd behavior: file reached the size limit and get eliminated, all logs are gone. I don't know in what case this might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

*Update: It was a rubbish answer, but with Nicholas Blumhardt's comment I think I can make it better*

Check out `FileLoggerConfigurationExtensions`

```
 //   rollOnFileSizeLimit:
 //     If true, a new file will be created when the file size limit is reached. Filenames
 //     will have a number appended in the format _NNN, with the first filename given
 //     no number.
```

I think combining `retainedFileCountLimit`, `fileSizeLimitBytes` and `rollOnFileSizeLimit` you could get close to one file :)

The following configuration should produce 2 files:

```
.WriteTo.File(
   logFilePath,
   rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
   fileSizeLimitBytes: 1_000_000,
   retainedFileCountLimit: 2))
```

Comment: If a file size is specified, it rolls no matter what by my testing.

Comment: @Roy2511 let us know what the parameters are, if that's the case - might be a bug, but more likely an interaction between different parameter values.

Comment: @tymtam `rollOnFileSizeLimit` would need to be `true` for this to work as the OP is requesting, I think. Specifying that, plus `retainedFileCountLimit: 2` should do roughly what's being asked. HTH!

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt Sorry can't reproduce it anymore. I was trying a lot of different settings and maybe accidentally left the rollOnFileSizeSetting as true. My bad.  

Great library though. Thanks for making it :) I chose Serilog over NLog because I found the startup performance of Serilog was much better.